# How to sendkeys ctrl and Mouse wheel?

Tags: c#, sendkeys

Use WebBrowser to browse folder paths.

And I want to make a zoom.

Really do this with the ctrl and mouse wheel.

I would like to do that with the code:

```
WebBrowser_Folder_Failes.Focus()
SendKeys.Send("^{+}")
```

Unfortunately, I failed.

How to sendkeys ctrl and Mouse wheel?

Comment: This works with HTML contents only.

Comment: You'll have to pinvoke SendInput, use MOUSEEVENTF_WHEEL.

Comment: How to sendkeys ctrl and Mouse wheel

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code.

```
 [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        private static extern void mouse_event(uint dwFlags, uint dx, uint dy, uint dwData, int dwExtraInfo);
```

It create method mouse_event in class. Then just use this method.

```
uint perSent = 10;
mouse_event(0x0800, 0,0,perSent ,0);//it will zoom 10 per sent
```

If you want understand more, check this: https://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.mouse_event
or just google mouseeventflags and use mouse_event.